I am unable to compile a c# application that uses the microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder json api with mono mcs under Ubuntu
I am attempting to compile a simple example code snippet that can be found here: but I haven't had any luck to get it to compile without errors.
First, I wrapped the code snippet on the web site into a main function like this:
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

internal class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(".\appsettings.json", false, true);
    IConfigurationRoot root = builder.Build();

    Console.WriteLine($"Hello, { root["weather"] } world!");
  }
}

My build script:
#!/bin/bash
mcs monotest.cs \
-r:/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/8.0.103/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll \
-r:/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/8.0.3/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll

However, I still get the following error:  monotest.cs(10,41): error CS0012: The type System.Object is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
(The extra quotes in the error message were removed before pasting here.)
I searched for "System.Runtime" in /usr/lib and found several different instances of this file name:
$ find /usr/lib -name "System.Runtime.dll"
/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/8.0.103/Microsoft/Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions/net461/lib/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.3/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.ubuntu.22.04-x64/8.0.3/runtimes/ubuntu.22.04-x64/lib/net8.0/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/dotnet/packs/NETStandard.Library.Ref/2.1.0/ref/netstandard2.1/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/8.0.3/ref/net8.0/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.5-api/Facades/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/Facades/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.6.1-api/Facades/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.7-api/Facades/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.5.1-api/Facades/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.6-api/Facades/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Facades/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.8-api/Facades/System.Runtime.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.7.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.dll

I have no idea which one of these to add to my script.  I tried a few of these but they just causes yet more errors like: error CS1070: The type System.Object has been forwarded to an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly System.Private.CoreLib... etc.
Maybe I need a whole shitload more of these with just the right combo but I was hoping someone would know the answer so I wouldn't have to try them all.
I just want to know if anyone else has tried something like this.
My OS:
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:  Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:  22.04
Codename: jammy


mono version:
$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 6.8.0.105 (Debian 6.8.0.105+dfsg-3.2 Wed Jun 30 05:34:49 UTC 2021)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
  TLS:           __thread
  SIGSEGV:       altstack
  Notifications: epoll
  Architecture:  amd64
  Disabled:      none
  Misc:          softdebug
  Interpreter:   yes
  LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
  Suspend:       hybrid
  GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)


BTW, if anyone wants to ask "what are you trying to do", here is the answer: nothing specific, I'm just trying to learn something.  I saw some code similar to this on a learning web site but I didn't want to go through the hassle of signing up for a Microsoft account just so that I could download Visual Studio Community Edition and run it on my Windows box.
Thanks in advance!

Then please learn that there is nothing worthy https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-end-of-mono/ You already have .NET 8 so stick to that please. Besides, Mono C# compiler has been updated for years, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-rough-history-of-the-so-many-c-compilers-f3a85500707c

@Lex Li: Thanks for the comment.  I believe you are saying that it's really a waste of time trying to fix problems in mono and look for another framework, is that right?  To that end, I just installed VS Code... hopefully I'll be able to do what I want on that. Cheers, Allan

After some fiddling around trying to figure out how to add assembly references in VS Code, I can compile and run my source.  I guess that's the way forward.

Barring any further information, I believe the right answer is: "Mono is not maintained... use VS Code.  Please refer to comments following original question."  Switching to a different framework solved my issue.  Thanks to @Lex Li for sending me in the right direction.
